# Monogame OpenGL Game crashes on some Windows 7 computers

Tags: windows, windows-7, crash, monogame

I'am learning some Gamedevelopment using Monogame.

I started a Windows OpenGL Project and everything works fine on my Win8 machine.

I have compiled the project and sent it to 2 People, both are using win7 x64 and one of them can't open the Game.

After that, I tested it on my other computer (also win7 x64) and I get the same problem, the game process starts, then the screen flashes (Aero seems to deactivate), then everything gets back to normal and the process of my game crashes without a message.

I'm sure, that there is no problem with my code, maybe some missing dlls but most of them are copied with the game

- Lidgren.Network.dll
- MonoGame.Framework.dll
- OpenTK.dll
- SDL.dll
- Tao.Sdl.dll

Sincerely

CarnVanBeck

Comment: The Aero switching off happens to my work computer and for some reason not my computer at home. I'm interested as to why this happens as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I fixed it using an OpenAL32 installer

I found the solution [here](http://monogame.codeplex.com/discussions/357014)

You have to install it, if your game doesn't work.

fixed it for me on my second computer.

Comment: That fixes it on my end as well! The flashing and zero disabling still happens though. Not sure why yet.

Answer (score 2):

If it's taking down Windows Aero, it might be a graphics issue. Compare the graphical capability of the Win7 machine that can run it with the one(s) that can't. Does the working one have a graphics card? I seem to remember Monogame having odd behaviour with the Reach graphics profile.